# Has anyone compared Dexie to localbase?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, dexie

Has anyone used both localbase and Dexie that can compare the two?

I am developing an application in Quasar/Vue/Electron, and using IndexedDB for my database.  I've been using localbase but it seems fairly limited in what it can do.  It seems Dexie may be more robust, and can auto-increment key fields, which I don't think localbase can do.

Also, if both are installed via npm, can they both be used at the same time? I'm mainly asking for when I switch from localbase to Dexie.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have any deep knowledge within that topic, since I started researching today, by my self. anyways, Google is always mentioning [IndexdDB Promised](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb) (idb), which has been made by Jake Archibald (a google employee) - it is open source, and seems to be the mostly used (as far as I can see - according to 1.204.956 weekly downloads on npm)...

There are some other [alternatives listed on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API#see_also), also maybe [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/) is worth a look as well...